# How to subscribe to Suspended messages in BizTalk?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I would like to subscribe to the suspended messages where the routing for failed messages is disabled. I don't want to enable this routing failure on receive port because it creates routing failure report leading to performance issues when the count is more.

How can I subscribe to suspended messages without the error report?

I have an orchestration that sends request and gets response based on correlation. If response not received within certain time, orchestration gets completed. If the response received after the timeout, message gets suspended as no subscriber found. I need to subscribe to these messages without impacting performance.

Comment: You can't subscribe to suspended messages unless you do enable routing for failed messages.   Can you let us know what you are trying to achieve?   e.g. if you want notifications of failed messages, you can subscribe to NACKs.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.I have an orchestration that sends request and gets response based on correlation. If response not received within certain time, orchestration gets completed. If the response received after the timeout, message gets suspended as no subscriber found. I need to subscribe to these messages without impacting performance.

Comment: OK.  Use the [edit] link under your question to add that detail to your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is have a send port that subscribes to all the response messages and that is configured to use a BizTalk Null Adapter.  This Null Adapter will swallow messages and discard them.

If your Orchestration instance is still active, it will also get a copy of the message, as you can have multiple subscribers to a message.

If your Orchestration instance has completed, then the port to the Null Adapter will consume and dispose of the message without any errors or suspended messages.

You can either write your own Null Adapter using the SDK Toolkit, or find one [ready built](http://www.integrationsoftware.se/products/biztalk-adapters/null-adapter-for-biztalk/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am really looking for this kind of a solution for my design. However I have never written any null adapter. can you please guide me more on this and any link/articles on the null adapter would be helpful.

Comment: Also, I am using BizTalk 2010. Is this feature available on 2010 version

Comment: @Techie It is not an out of the box feature. I've already given you a link to one place where you can download a pre-built Null Adapter for BizTalk (compatible with BizTalk 2006 or later) so hopefully works for 2010.  Other than that, just do a Google search for BizTalk Null Adapter to find other resources.   Another option would just be to write the messages to a file location and have another process clean those up.

Comment: Just went through the null adapter articles.It will actually dispose the messages. But in my case, I need to handle these messages(received after timeout) with other business logic i.e subscribing to orchestrations. Can I still use null adapter in this case

Comment: @Techie So what do you want to do with the message if the Orchestration has timed out?

Comment: I need to read the messages and send it to another system if orchestration has timed out

Comment: @Techie Then you will probably have to do it in the Orchestration, after the initial timeout have it listening for any late messages and send those off to another system, or have it emit a message to spin up another Orchestration that can then listen for the late message.